# Codeigniter Access DB object in another model

Tags: codeigniter

In Codeigniter models is there a way to make this work?

```
class Mdl_my_model extends CI_Model
{
protected $my_db = NULL;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->my_db = $this->load->database('my_db', TRUE);
}

public function some_cool_method()
{
    $this->load->model('Mdl_other_model');
    $this->Mdl_other_model->other_method();
}
}
```

Can model below make use of the $my_db object or do I have to load db again?

```
class Mdl_other_model extends CI_Model
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function other_method()
{
    //is it possible to use the $my_db object here?
}
}
```

Comment: If you specifically want to load multiple databases and one is already the default accessible via `$this->db` then you could inject the connection via a setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to load the database on to a class property. You can simple just load it as you do a model `$this->load->database('name')`. It should be accessible to everything beneath when you load it. However I usually just load it in a `MY_Controller` on the first line in `__construct` to which I extend all my separate controllers off of.

If you are trying to assign different database names to individual properties (which is the only reason why you would assign it as you are doing), you would have to make your other model extend the first and then you can access that property. But this means whenever you load the other model you have to load the first one first. Generally I would also then assign them in to public properties in `MY_Controller` controller and the variable would be available throughout.

Comment: I will also be using the default db in the same class so I would not be able to use `$this->load->database('name')`.  I should have made that clear.  So I would have `$this->load->database();` and `$my_db = $this->load->database('my_db');` in the same model.  The models that will be also using $my_db would all be loaded by the first model so your second suggestion about extending may work.  Thanks!

Comment: @TomVaughan but personally, I think that you might be better off loading them individually instead of extending. This way you don't have to load both models one after the other if you just need one. That being said, if you use the second connection a lot (more than a few models), it might be a good idea to go the `MY_Controller` route. In codeigniter, inheritance is kindof a PITA.

Comment: The project I am working on is for syncing quickbooks to db so in a single session there can be a large number of requests going back and forth between quickbooks and server.  I have a main model with many other models that do stuff like syncing customer, invoices, etc.  In this particular use case extending all of the models that are loaded by the main model makes the most sense.  I already have it coded and it works great.